# Upper Bounding Hausdorff Measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Let $(S, \rho)$ be an arbitrary metric space. Define $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$.

I have a mathematical object in the form of $Lip(f) diam(S)$ where $$\Lambda(f) = Lip(f)=\sup_{x,y \in S} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{\rho(x,y)}$$
$$D(S) = diam(S) = \sup_{x,y \in S} \rho(x,y)$$

We can rewrite $\Lambda(f) D(S)$ as $\Lambda(f) *\mathcal{H}^1_{D(S)}(S)$ where $$\mathcal{H}^d_{\delta}=inf[\sum_{i=1}^\infty\ D(U_i)^d : \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} U_i \supseteq S, D(U_i) \leq \delta ]$$

How can we upperbound this object? Is there an inequality in the form $$\mathcal{H}^1_{\delta}(S) \leq c(\delta) \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\mathcal{H}^1_\epsilon(S)$$

Comment: Saying "$\mathcal H$ is the Hausdorff measure" is meaningless - there are many different Hausdorff measures, one for each "dimension". And what do you mean by $\mathcal H_\delta$? If not for the earlier confusion I'd assume that meant $\delta$-dimensional Hausdorff measure, but on that assumpption asking whether it's bounded by "the" Hausdorff measure $\mathcal H$ doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I added some more details.Let me know if it's still confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true that $D(S)=\mathcal H_{D(S)}^1(S)$. For example if $S=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ then $D(S)=3$ while $\mathcal H_3^1(S)=2$. (I think it's clearly true if $S$ is connected.)

The inequality you ask about is trivial, with $c(\delta)=1$. If $A\subset B$ then $\inf A\ge\inf B$; hence if $0\le\epsilon\le\delta$ then $\mathcal H_\delta^1(S)\le\mathcal H_\epsilon^1(S)$.

Comment: Can we bound $\Lambda(f)D(S)$ through any Hausdorff measure?

Comment: Not without some hypotheses. If $S=\{0,1\}$ then $\mathcal H^d(S)=0$ for every $d>0$.